# Advice on securing/encrypting a code

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I'm developing an application that on one side produces a code with certain information about a purchase, wich includes a credit information. For example, you could buy a given number of minutes to spend in a public PC on a cybercafe, and you receive a ticket with a number/code with that ammount of minutes, which is then decoded and processed by the PC blocking software in the public PC.
The full length of that information (including date of purchase, an ID, and so on) is about 12 bytes. I need to secure that data, obviously, as much as i need to make it unalterable.
I don't have experience on cryptography but have been reading a lot the last few days, so i came up with an scheme in which i encrypt the data using Twofish in CFB mode (to keep the ciphertext small), and add a 4 bytes long IV, randomly generated. I realize it's a short IV, but the reasoning behind is that an attacker should grab an apparently ridiculous ammount of tickets to become a thread with an IV of 65535 variations.
The problem i see (let alone the ones i miss) is that i also need to authenticate the code, since in CFB mode, a small change in the ciphertext produces just a small change in the plaintext, so anybody could change, for instance, its ticket's credit by just changing an A for a B.
So, first question is: is there any obvious problem in using the CRC16 of the plaintext as IV, and add it (unencrypted) to the encrypted code to use it both for authentication and IV? I repeat i'm not in cryptography, but it 'feels' odd to put some information about the plaintext unencrypted along with the cyphertext. But is just the gut feeling.
Or, instead, should i use a stream cipher? Which one could make a big change (/mess up) the plaintext from a small change in ciphertext. Is this related to the error propagation property in the cipher mode of operation?

Some guide, please?
Thanks a lot.
By the way, if that matters, im using mcrypt on PHP.

I must add that the other end of the app, the one that reads the ticket, is not (and cannot be) online. Sorry for that ommision.

Comment: I would rather hand out random numbers and have the client PC:s ask a license server for the purchase information associated with that random number.

Comment: Thanks Albin. This whole scheme is derived from the fact that the other end of the app (the one exemplified with the public PC) is not online. I thik i took for granted that it was implied. I'm sorry for that. I'll edit.

Comment: It's pointless to use an IV that is derived from the plain text. The whole point of an IV is to produce different cipher texts from the same plain text.

Comment: That's right erickson. Right and straight like a slap in the back of my head. My scrambled head. Thanks a lot. So cannot use any hash as IV. Can i avoid the use of the hash by means of a different encryption method? Or should i add the hash AND the IV to the code, which i'd rather avoid doing?

Comment: There are cipher modes like EAX and CCM that provide integrity and privacy, but they are probably too bulky to use for a code that a user can easily type. What if you just give them an HMAC, and let them enter the message itself? Like they input the date, ID, and time limit, plus a verification code. If the code matches their input, they are good to go.

Comment: Hm. I was thinking of printing the whole thing in a codebar (so the user won't have to type anything), but if i can't go along whith it, it could be a viable alternative the one you suggest. Anyway, also lead me to think from another angle. Appreciate that. Thanks, erickson

Comment: Well... One of my originals concerns was about publishing a hash of the content along with the content, so i can use it on the other end for authentication. I still feel uncomfortable doing it, but in the lack of technical knowledge, i'll opt for adding a CRC16 AND a random IV to the encrypted code to avoid the stupid mistake i would have made(use the CRC16 as IV). Thx erickson again. Any other points are welcomed. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is either an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) or, if you cannot secure the client PCs, a digital signature, not encryption.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Am i wrong assuming that in that case i still need to send the information as well as the HMAC? I mean, is your advice to replace the CRC16 part of my scheme, only? If so, it seems that the length of the ticket would become impractical. If i'm wrong, sorry, please clarify me.

Comment: Yes, it will require more bits to do this securely. You can have secure tickets, short tickets, or disconnected verification: pick two.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some salt and produce an MD5 hash, delivered right with the plaintext

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. MD5 hash seems too long for my needs, and maybe (hopefully) an overkill. The ticket would become impractical. Anyway, my conceptual concern remains the same about adding unencrypted information about the plaintext, even realizing that an MD5 is a lot less information than a CRC16.

Comment: You have to be careful using a hash like that because an attacker could easily append some more data to the end of the message and update the hash to match. The format of the message would have to have some sort of "end of message" marker or be of fixed length for this approach to be secure.

Comment: You could take a substring from the hash. Although .... I am not an encryption expert and hope this is not really bad advice!

Comment: The substring of the hash seems reasonable to me. Though i think it has the same flaw as the crc16. ie: only 65536 variations, which could be less than desirable with big ammounts of data being secured. Since this is not the case (or doesn't seems to be), it could work as well.

Comment: Andrew, the data i'm using is in fact strongly formatted. For instance, it has a field of 10 bits for the credit, another of 5 for the day, 4 for the month, etc. So it woudn't be a problem if the attack consist in adding information to match the hash. Am i right?

Comment: When you generate the hash, you should add some constant *secret* characters (salt) to the plaintext yourself

Comment: But then i'd not know how to match the hash on the other side, unless i send the secret salt, which wouldn't be secret anymore and would put me back in the same situation.

Comment: Well, of course they can hack your software on the PC and discover what the salt is. But, if they can do that, they can just as well bypass your check.

Comment: No, i didn't mean that, of course. I mean that i should send the salt along with the code to be able to match the hash on the "receiving" end.

Comment: I would implement the salt as a predefined constant on both ends instead of sending it.

Comment: Oh. I'll think about this. Could work, althogh my first feeling is it would be kind of like having a different hash, and, like erickson made me see, it would lead to the same ciphertext for the same plaintext, rendering it pointless. But, again, i have to think it through. Thanks a lot for the ideas Eduardo!